# Matlab, inserting the value of a vector in 3d matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 3D matrix `a` and a vector `a1`. The size of `a1` changes for each iteration. Now I want to input this vector into a certain position in a whose 2nd and 3rd column is defined. Something like this,

```
a(:,3,4)=a1;
```

But it gets the error `"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
subscripts"`. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of `a1`changes at each iteration, you will need to preallocate `a` to the maximum size and use explicit subscripts for assignation

```
a = zeros(5,5,5)
a(1:length(a1),3,4)=a1;
```

Alternatively you can use a cell-array:

```
a{3,4} = a1
```

The cell array will be able to store vectors of different lengths.